# Как выбрать строку с максимальным параметром MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица настроек для доменов

```
id   домен  опция  значение
1    0      имя    по умолчанию
2    1      имя    новый
3    2      имя    старый
4    0      адрес  по умолчанию
5    1      адрес  новый
6    2      адрес  старый
7    0      мыло   по умолчанию мыло
```

как из такой таблицы выбрать запросом настройки для домена (это число int) 1

мы должны получить все настройки которые относятся к 1 домену это записи id=2,5, но там где не указано конкретной настройки - мы должны взять общую настройку тоесть с id=7

получаем

```
id   домен  опция  значение
2    1      имя    новый
5    1      адрес  новый
7    0      мыло   по умолчанию мыло
```

как сделать такой запрос? делаю

```
SELECT * FROM settings 
WHERE d in (0,1)
GROUP BY `опция`
```

но мне кажется тут надо как то MAX функцией воспользоваться, но она не работает со строками, надо по идее max(домен) и мах(значение) ????

Comment: такая структура выбрана с целью усложнить жизнь?

Comment: нет, просто на 1 папке 2 домена, тоесть на одном движке. но у них разные шаблоны, настройки, емайлы и тд...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так будет по логике. Берем все значения по дефолту и смотрим какие значения для данного домена заполнены.

```
select 
  IF (dom.`option` IS NULL, def.`id`, dom.`id`) as `id`, 
  IF (dom.`domain` IS NULL, def.`domain`, dom.`domain`) as `domain`, 
  IF (dom.`option` IS NULL, def.`option`, dom.`option`) as `option`, 
  IF (dom.`option` IS NULL, def.`value`, dom.`value`) as `value`
from
  settings def
  left join settings dom on 
    def.`option` = dom.`option`
    and dom.`domain` = 1    
where
    def.`domain` = 0
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12d4e7/9)

Comment: а еще такой вопрос я придумал как решить проблему проще - 2 запросами.

1. SELECT * FROM settings WHERE d=0 // выбираем общие настройки
2. SELECT * FROM settings WHERE d=1 // выбираем настройки 1 домена

это конструкция как будет работать быстрее чем составной запрос? или нет?

Comment: сайт скинули клевый для тестов) а там можно как то время работы протестировать?

Comment: @armenka у вас столько настроек, что нужно время замерять? ) Одним запросом как в ответе, у вас двумя запросами. Делайте как вам удобнее.  
А почему вы просто не сохраняете дефолтовые настройки в настройки самого домена (простым копированием) при редактировании?

Comment: что значит столько настроек? не понимаю вопроса... Это нужно для сайта у которого привязанно несколько доменов просмотров в день до 2000 вы ж понимаете что нужно оптимизоровать запросы, тк формация из бд запрашивается кажды раз для нового просмотра
вот и спрашиваю что быстрее работает

Comment: @armenka, если честно не совсем понимаю что конкретно вы хотите оптимизировать. вы придумали систему хранения настроек, теперь либо обрабатываете ее в php (получив все и вся и циклом отбирать нужное), либо в sql, как показано в ответе. об оптимизации тут речи не идет. у вас в вопросе "как сделать?" написано - вот так.

Comment: @armenka время измерять бесполезно, а explain в sqlfiddle можно.